# How to install a local conda package file

Tags: anaconda, conda

I'm new to conda. Is there a way I can build the package somewhere, move it to another environment and install it without connect to the internet?

For example we want to have a package specifically for xgboost users. We want have these in the meta.yaml:

```
package:
  name: xgboost-test
  version: 1.0 

build:
  skip_compile_pyc:
    - "*"

# needs channels: conda-forge
requirements:
  host:
    - python
    - pip
    - conda
  run:
    - python 
    - pip
    - git
    - conda
    - nb_conda
    - pandas
    - xgboost==1.1.1
```

After building a new package which contains all above, we have a new package named xgboost-test-1.0.20221206-py37_0.tar.bz2.

Is there any way I can only move this new package to another computer and install it over there, without setting the channel, or not connect to the internew? I don't think it's convenient to setup a channel every time. I thought there is a way which I can simply install the new package file, that's more quick and straight forward.

The best way I know is copy the whole channel folder to the new environment and install over there. The other way I know is to download the package file, use `conda index` to initialize the channel, and install it by `conda install -c file:///path/to/local/channel`.
But I'm wondering if there is a way just move the package itself, not the whole channel folder. I thought there is a way which I can simply install the new package file, that's more quick and straight forward.